# Fill out login information with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I access a few websites to download client data every 30 minutes. Selenium (python) helps me automatically fill out all the sign-in information and control all the subsequent selection/clicking steps. With this set-up, I don't ever need to manually click anything. However, with one particular page https://services.ehousingplus.com/Default.htm, I can't seem to fill out the 'User Name'/'Password' nor can I click the Login button. If fact, I can't use the `browser.find_element_by_xpath()` to control any elements on the webpage at all. Not sure if it uses any special technology. Please help.

I use code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://services.ehousingplus.com/Default.htm")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#igtxtmyAuthentication_utxeUserName')
```

There is a notice on the webpage saying it supports only IE 8/9. But I think that restriction is only on the subsequent steps after logging in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements are inside of a frame.  Selenium can only access elements in the current frame.  In order to access the login elements on that page, you need to switch to the frame that contains the elements.

You'll need to use:

```
browser.get("https://services.ehousingplus.com/Default.htm")
browser.switch_to_frame("HDSApplications")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#igtxtmyAuthentication_utxeUserName')
```

In order to move back to the top frame, you'll need to use:

```
browser.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new HTML. Great to know the concept of frame.